# Laravel Eloquent get() indexed by primary key id

Tags: laravel, hashmap, eloquent

I often find it very useful to index my results by the primary key id.

Example:

```
$out = [];

$users = User::where('created_at', '>=', '2015-01-01')->get();

foreach ($users as $user) {
    $out[$user->id] = $user;
}

return $out;
```

Is there anyway to do this in one shot with Eloquent?  It's not useful to use the 0...n index.

Comment: Just out of interest, what is the use case here?

Comment: @Wader The use case is that I get do quicker lookup on the primary key.   isset($out[2134]) is constant lookup because of hashmap.  Instead of having do do a for loop to look for 2134

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstood, but isn't that what [$collection->getDictionary()](http://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection.html#method_getDictionary) does? So: `$users = User::where('created_at', '>=', '2015-01-01')->get()->getDictionary();`

Comment: @Ciccio that the answer i'm looking for.  :)  Please submit your answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @Yada done. Glad it helped. :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can accomplish this by using [getDictionary()](http://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection.html#method_getDictionary) on your collection.

Like so:

```
$users = User::where('created_at', '>=', '2015-01-01')->get()->getDictionary();
```

---

Note: in newer version of Laravel (5.2+), getDictionary() was removed; [keyBy()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-keyby) can be used instead:

```
$users = User::where('created_at', '>=', '2015-01-01')->get()->keyBy('id');
```

Answer (score 1):

I created my own solution by having a super Model that extends Eloquent.

Full solution:
https://gist.github.com/yadakhov/741173ae893c1042973b

```
/**
 * Where In Hashed by primary key
 *
 * @param array $ids
 * @return array
 */
public static function whereInHash(array $ids, $column = 'primaryKey')
{
    $modelName = get_called_class();
    $primaryKey = static::getPrimaryKey();
    if ($column === 'primaryKey') {
        $column = $primaryKey;
    }
    $rows = $modelName::whereIn($column, $ids)->get();
    $out = [];
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        $out[$row->$primaryKey] = $row;
    }
    return $out;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **keyBy()**

```
$users = User::where('created_at', '>=', '2015-01-01')->get()->keyBy('id')->toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Not with eloquent but this is potentially nicer option than looping through all the results.

```
$users = Users::all();

return array_combine($users->modelKeys(), $users);
```